# Volume is too low all the time and becomes loud enough only when resuming from suspend

Tags: 11.10, sound, laptop

The system volume of my notebook is  too low comparing with using headphone or running it on windows7. I can hardly hear the sound even if the volume slider  was moved to maximum. Today after I had used my laptop for half a day or so ,I opened mplayer to listen mp3 and found the sound is so loud and clear. I was so excited.  I tried many times to play kinds of movies,mp3 and flash to make sure it's not a  cheat. Yep, the sound became loud and clear,it is true.Then I restarted my computer to verify the inconceivability appearance. The sound returned back to low level as before .After trying many times now  I can confirm the problem:

The volume is too low to tolerate all the time. Only after resuming from suspend does the sound become loud and clear enough. But it becomes too low again after restarting or resuming from hibernation. Have you got any suggestions?

FYI,

```
$ sudo head -1 /proc/asound/card0/codec#0
Codec: IDT 92HD81B1C5

$ aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****

card 0: Intel [HDA Intel], device 0: STAC92xx Analog [STAC92xx Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

Alsamixer -c 0
screenshot:

[image: Alsamixer]

Comment: I should note that ALSA isn't the real sound system used in Ubuntu. The actual system is Pulse Audio, which has an ALSA plugin. Thus, I wouldn't trust AlsaMixer to display relevant data. Try the Sound Settings dialog, or from the command line `pacmd`.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions.  I have moved all of the adjustable sliders in Sound Settings dialog to maximum but it doesn't work. Excuse me for my ignorance about pacmd.  I don't know how to offer you any useful output infomation from that tool.

Comment: If moving the sliders to the max doesn't help, then I'm out of ideas.

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. I am flagging this for closure. Regards,

Comment: Try updating your kernel. If the problem persists, this question should instead be filed as a bug report, and [as such](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) is off-topic, thanks! [Instructions here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the `.pulse` directory in your home folder, then reboot.

`rm -rf ~/.pulse`